# RSS feed of reputation changes? Comments?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, feed

I'd like some way to get notices of comments people make to my (questions, answers, comments), as well as changes to my reputation.  Any chance that this could be added?

I'm sure I could script something up to scrape the webpage, but that's a lot less friendly than having it built in :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can now mark this as complete. I have written a small app that does exactly this.

### [Stack2RSS](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service)

Stack2RSS takes an API request and converts it into an RSS feed that you can then subscribe to. Because the API is so flexible, stack2rss is very flexible.

Answering your question, here is the feed for comments people post to you on Meta Stack Overflow:

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/users/127120/mentioned

And for recent reputation changes:

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/users/127120/reputation

Comment: Nice work, but the timeline is not recent reputation it is "recent stuff done". It seems pretty similar to the feed at http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/127120 - EDIT: this is still half the original poster's question answered. I just wanted to be pedantic :-)

Comment: @richq: Thanks for mentioning this... I certainly want this tool to be the best it can be... I'm sure there is a feed I can build that includes rep. changes. I'll look into it.

Comment: This doesn't show my rep changes.  How does that do what I'm looking for?

Comment: @Bill: My mistake. I have fixed the link.

Comment: Your API key is exposed in this, but I assume you would have hid it if you could.

Comment: @Jon: Ya, there's nothing I can do about it... and it's not a problem.

Comment: Alright, that works.  Good enough :)

Comment: And, it's gone.  Both examples give me a 404 now.

Answer (score 3):

Native RSS feed for comments:

- `https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/`user-id`/responses`
- `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/`user-id`/responses`
- Replace `user-id` with your own id. You can find your id in the URL of your own profile.

To get the feed for any domain:

1. Go to your account profile
2. Check for "user feed" at the bottom
3. add `/responses` to the URL