# Include comments in RSS feed

Tags: feature-request, comments, feed

I've been using RSS feeds on questions more and more often, but they don't include comments.  Those comments might be more information, clarification, requests for those, etc. which I'd be interested in.

Could comments be included in RSS feeds, or could a separate feed be added that includes comments? (I'm undecided between just comments or comments + answers for an additional feed.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36738/any-feed-for-stackoverflow-that-also-has-comments-in-rss and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/rss-feed-for-responses-to-your-posts and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28172/rss-feed-of-reputation-changes-comments