# How to get "useful" count and "accepted answer" in the Stack Overflow RSS feed?

Tags: support, feed

How can I get "useful" count and "accepted answer" in the Stack Overflow RSS feed?

Any pointers are highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the URL for the RSS feed?

Comment: What are you going to use it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming by *“useful” count* is meant *votes*, and [some tag RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c), yes, this information is in the `re:rank` tag, 0 votes for the below example question with an accepted answer. However the information about an accepted answer is not available and must be obtained by some other means, e.g. screen scraping or through the [Stack Exchange API](https://stackapps.com/faq).

As an alternative you might be able to use [Stack2RSS](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-with-a-feed-browser-and-email-s). Samples: *[RSS feed for unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42525/anyway-to-get-a-rss-feed-for-unanswered-questions/64978#64978)* and *[RSS feed for a user's answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28172)*.

---

Start of the entry for *[Get my own IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700455/get-my-own-ip-address)*:

```
<entry>
    <id>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700455/get-my-own-ip-address</id>
    <re:rank scheme="http://stackoverflow.com">0</re:rank>
    <title type="text">Get my own IP address</title>
    <category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c/tags" term="c"/><category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c/tags" term="linux"/><category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c/tags" term="networking"/>
    <author>
        <name>michelemarcon</name>
        <uri>https://stackoverflow.com/users/15173</uri>
    </author>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700455/get-my-own-ip-address" />
    <published>2011-04-18T08:44:52Z</published>
    <updated>2011-04-18T10:35:08Z</updated>
    <summary type="html">
        &lt;p&gt;If I use &lt;code&gt;getHostByName()&lt;/code&gt; I only get &quot;127.0.0.1&quot;, because it is written on /etc/host, but this is not useful to me.&lt;/p&gt;
```