# RSS feed for questions which includes comments and \ or edits

Tags: feature-request, support, feed

**Request summary**

I would like to read an RSS feed on specified questions which includes also comments and possibly edits on that page.

**My best tries**

Before asking others to solve this for me, I tried some basic search and existing functionality:

- The current feed on the bottom of the page (e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/12345678`) only notifies when answers are posted.
- [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28172/rss-feed-of-reputation-changes-comments) I found [this](http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com) solution, but didn't manage to get it working. I am not sure if it's not operational anymore or I am not using it right.
- [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36738/is-there-a-feed-for-stack-overflow-that-also-has-comments-in-rss) I found a suggestion related to the timeline, but didn't manage to do anything with it.

**Related links and previous cases**

I have searched for previous questions on this topic and found that it, or a similar variant, has been asked about several times already. Unfortunately, the discussions are old (outdated or defunct). Some examples are:

- [Include comments in RSS feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46242/) .
- [What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/)  (and the links within).

**Extended discussion**

Currently, you will receive inbox notifications for comments directed at you (pinged with `@`), and you can opt for the RSS feed for answers for a specified question. However, many times users will not reply to your comments with the `@` mechanic (seems that no one reads the usage guide for this site(s)) and I find myself faced with the following choices: forget about the question until I get a proper notification and blame the user for not following the site's proper usage, or manually checking myself a list of questions periodically to see if something new happened. A similar case can be made for edits, where a user edits their question (usually in response to a comment), but does not notify that the edit has been made.

For these reasons, I would like to be notified when such changes occur. Even if there is a new comment on an answer, which seemingly is irrelevant to me, I would rather be notified as I am already invested in the question.

**Final note on Favorites**

I am aware that marking a question as favorite is a way to know when something changed there (not sure exactly what are all the triggers), but

- You don't get a notification for what exactly changed and how many changes occurred.
- Favorites is a place for your... favorites, similar to bookmarks. Watching questions is not the same (as indicated by the supplied RSS feed).

  - Some questions you store because you like them and not because you want updates on them.
  - For my purpose, the list of watched questions is very dynamic (questions go in and out of it quickly), unlike favorites which seems to me to be built more towards the long run.

**What solution can you suggest?**